# How to deactivate user (i.e. how to change is_active) in Flask?

Tags: flask

In my app if a user does something against the rules I want to make it so they can't log in. After reading the Flask docs, it seems like is_active is the thing to use. But I don't know how to set is_active to False. For example, I'm able to change if is_authenticated is set to True/False by using login_user() and logout_user(). But I don't know how to change is_active.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I am using UserMixin, which automatically populates the is_active() method. However, I still needed to add an is_active field to the user model. So after adding this field I was able to change it through current_user.is_active = False, and then the login_user() function automatically disallowed login by detecting that is_active is False.